# Auto Resizing the webpage in WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I am trying to load a webpage using a `webview`

```
String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");  

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
//webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
//myWebView.loadUrl(url);
myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

This is my current code, however the webpage is not resized in any way.

If I load the same webpage using a browser in the emulator, the webpage is resized and shown correctly. Can someone help me?

myWebView.setInitialScale(50); This helps and resizes the webpage however there is still a small part of the webpage on the left missing.

Is this the correct solution:
[How to create an android webview that is the same as the android default browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15064557/how-to-create-an-android-webview-that-is-the-same-as-the-android-default-browser?rq=1)

Has someone done something different?

It now load the webpage as I want to but then it has too mush white space. The text is all cramped up in 1 column and doesn't spread over the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the initial zoom/width for a webview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808532/how-to-set-the-initial-zoom-width-for-a-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

```
myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: This doesn't help as it mangles everything into 1 column. Atleast previously it loaded the page correctly but I could only see half the page.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
myWebView.setInitialScale(1);
```

Comment: Using this I just get a tiny box at the top of the page which I believe is the whole page scaled down to 1 pixel.